# Load custom configuration section from various locations

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently i'm facing an issue with a framework I'm developing.
I have a custom configuration section that handles data caching.

The configuration for this is stored in the `web.config` of the application as shown below.

```
<configSections>
<section name="CachingProviders"
         type="Data.Caching.Providers.Configuration.CachingProviderConfigurationSection, Data.Caching" />
</configSections>

<!-- Start the DCF configuration here. -->
<CachingProviders>
<!-- Providers definition:
A provider is the object that make sure that the item can be stored in the cache or not.
-->
<Providers>
  <Provider Name="SlidingCachingProvider" Time="5" IsDefault="False"
            Type="Data.Caching.Providers.SlidingProvider, Data.Caching.Providers" />
  <Provider Name="AbsoluteCachingProvider" Time="5" IsDefault="False"
            Type="Data.Caching.Providers.AbsoluteProvider, Data.Caching.Providers" />
</Providers>
</CachingProviders>
```

Now, the code is working fine, I'm reading the configuration from the web.config

But now I want to know if there's an easy way to transform my code so that the configuration can be done in a seperate file in the bin directory, for example: `data-caching.config`

I know there is a solution that in the custom config section you define which file to load, but I want to keep my web.config as clean as possible, which means that I don't want to add a single thing if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `configSource` attribute to your `Providers` node as:

```
<Providers configSource="providers.config"/>
```

See [here](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Webconfig-magic-configSource-and-file-attributes.aspx) and [here](http://sunali.com/en/2008/01/23/configsource-property-dividing-configuration-files-into-pieces/). This should work for custom sections as well.